# Oracle function call fails sometimes for native query

Tags: java, oracle, function

I'm doing password obfuscation with some oracle function I inherited.

This is the error in the log file:

```
    2019-07-17 12:50:43 DEBUG JobDAO:2179 - Decrypting with SQL=select XXX_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT_PASSWORD.get_decrypted_password(?,?,?,?) from dual
2019-07-17 12:50:43 DEBUG JobDAO:2180 - Decrypting parameters=SERVER_SERVICES,PASSWORD,SERVER_SERVICES_ID,101
2019-07-17 12:50:43 DEBUG JobDAO:2192 - Error while decrypting encrypted password for SERVER_SERVICES--PASSWORD--SERVER_SERVICES_ID--101 org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
2019-07-17 12:50:43 DEBUG MonitorJob:2087 - Could not decrypt password for tomcat7-8888
2019-07-17 12:50:43 DEBUG JobDAO:2179 - Decrypting with SQL=select XXX_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT_PASSWORD.get_decrypted_password(?,?,?,?) from dual
2019-07-17 12:50:43 DEBUG JobDAO:2180 - Decrypting parameters=SERVER_LOGFILES,LOGFILE_PASSWORD,SERVER_LOGFILES_ID,101
```

Note that the second call appears to be successful, and executing the query manually in SQL developer also works.

What can cause one call to fail while the next one works?

The java code is:

```
public String getDecryptedPassword(String tableName, String columnName,
        String tableId, String tableIdVal)
{
    try
    {
        String callFnEncDec = "select XXX_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT_PASSWORD.get_decrypted_password(?,?,?,?) from dual";
        logger.debug("Decrypting with SQL=" + callFnEncDec);
        //logger.debug("Decrypting parameters=" + tableName + "," + columnName + "," +tableId + "," +tableIdVal);

        Query callFnEncDecQuery = entityManager
                .createNativeQuery(callFnEncDec);
        callFnEncDecQuery.setParameter(1, tableName);
        callFnEncDecQuery.setParameter(2, columnName);
        callFnEncDecQuery.setParameter(3, tableId);
        callFnEncDecQuery.setParameter(4, tableIdVal);

        return (String) callFnEncDecQuery.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.debug("Error while decrypting encrypted password for "
                + tableName + "--" + columnName + "--" + tableId + "--"
                + tableIdVal + " " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;

}
```

The decryption function is this:

```
  l_key RAW(128) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('secret_password');

FUNCTION get_decrypted_password( table_name IN varchar2,column_name IN varchar2,table_id IN varchar2,table_id_val IN varchar2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
     encrypted_pas varchar2(100);
     decrypted_pas varchar2(100);

   BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || column_name || ' from ' || table_name || ' where ' || table_id || ' = ' || table_id_val
         INTO encrypted_pas;
         Select decrypt_val(encrypted_pas) into decrypted_pas from dual;
          return decrypt_val(encrypted_pas);
  END get_decrypted_password;

END encrypt_decrypt_password;

FUNCTION decrypt_val( p_val IN varchar2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    l_decrypted RAW(2048);
    l_val RAW(2048) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_val);
   BEGIN
         l_decrypted := dbms_crypto.decrypt
                ( src =>  l_val,
                  typ => dbms_crypto.des_cbc_pkcs5,
                  key => l_key );

         return utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(l_decrypted);

  END decrypt_val;
```

Update: I renamed the column "PASSWORD" to "SERVER_PASSWORD" to rule out problems with Oracle keywords here. The problem persists.

Update: I still have this issue. It seems to resolve when I update the SERVER_PASSWORD column and commit twice.

When the error occurs, the following is the output:

```
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO_FFI", line 67
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO", line 44
ORA-06512: at "XXX_CONFIGURATION.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT_PASSWORD", line 32
ORA-06512: at "XXX_CONFIGURATION.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT_PASSWORD", line 65
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: It is a long shot, but is there possibility that you are trying to insert something into the "tableName" table and that it is locked? Also did you check all parameter values are they the same for successful and unsuccesfull calls?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the contents of `XXX_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.ENCRYPT_DECRYPT_PASSWORD.get_decrypted_password`, as the issue most likely lies in there.

Comment: The PL/SQL function named `get_decrypted_password` calls another function named `decrypt_val`. Can you post that function's code?

Comment: The parameters are indeed different the second time. But I now have another issue, a command that is much later has a javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Comment: By the way, you've left that code wide open for SQL injection, which is pretty bad. Please use the relevant function in the `dbms_assert` package to validate your column and table name inputs, and use a bind variable to bind the table_id_val, in your execute immediate statement.

Comment: Currently none of the values come from user input, so I can live with the SQL Injection

Comment: Is there a way to reset an entityManager?

Comment: That's not really a good excuse, though, especially when it's so easy to mitigate the problem.

Comment: Yes maybe, but changing the function does not address the problem I am having, and instead of reducing the errors it requires me to test all other functionalities that rely on the decryption.

Comment: Where is declared/set `l_key`?

Comment: `l_key` is declared and set in the `ENCRYPT_DECRYPT_PASSWORD` package along with the two functions.

Comment: You write: "The parameters are indeed different the second time. But I now have another issue, a command that is much later has a javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly " - so what is this question about, exactly? If you have another question and this was solved, this should be closed.

Comment: also, user input is not the only way sql concatenation can be a problem. Consider, for example, values having reserved SQL keywords in there somewhere, causing havoc in the database.

Comment: If I call the function for the first decryption, it will cause a RollbackException in a completely different location. The latter issue is thus linked to the first issue. I still haven't solved the first issue, and what is puzzling me is that the call is working fine from the SQL developer.

Comment: I now have a workaround: Call the function from a fresh new Connection to oracle. I still would like to know the issue and how to detect this situation on the entitymanager.

Comment: Uhm workaround doesn't work, there is an error raised by SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO_FFI". This is strange, I am using the same password on the second decryption and that one works.